# Project Euler Q.2 Ruby a[i] if a[i] % 2 == 0 not working

Tags: arrays, ruby

Here's a link to my Github 
https://github.com/kuanhsuh/projecteuler/blob/master/2redo.rb

My Question is in line 26:

```
c << a[i] if a[i] % 2 == 0
```

This method ignores the last even number of the Fibonacci sequence, and I dont know why.

My array A has 3524578, and this should be pushed to array C but it doesn't get pushed.

If i use the select method in line 29. It works fine. 
So how come the code in line 26 doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: By Stack Overflow rules, the question should be as self-sufficient as possible, with the minimal example needed to demonstrate the problem inside the question itself; links are just bonus. Please keep it in mind in the future.

Comment: Please respect the time of the people who help you. Your code should be as easy as possible for them to read and understand.  This means: descriptive identifier names (not `a`, `b`, `c`), and disabled debug code removed.  In addition, when referring to large integers, it's helpful to use underscores in your code and documentation, such as 4_000_000 and 3_524_578.

Comment: (Regarding my previous comment, it is legal in Ruby to use underscores in numeric constants.)

Comment: I'm sorry i'll keep in mind in the future

Comment: A small thing: you can write `n.even?` or `n.odd?`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the computed values for `i, i = 27, 28, 29, 30`. Recall `limit #=> 4_000_000`.

```
i #=> 27
a[27] + a[28] #=> 514_229 + 832_040 #=> 1_346_269 < 4_000_000 #=> true # so continue
c.last #=> 196_418 #=> unchanged
b #=> 1_346_269
a #=> [..., 514229, 832040, 1346269]

i #=> 28
a[28] + a[29] #=> 832040 + 1346269 #=> 2178309 < 4000000 #=> true, so continue
c.last #=> 832_040 # c.last changes
b #=> 2_178_309
a #=> [..., 832040, 1346269, 2178309]

i #=> 29
a[29] + a[30] #=> 1346269 + 2178309 #=> 3524578 < 4000000 #=> true, so continue
c.last #=> 832_040 # unchanged
b #=> 3_524_578
a #=> [..., 1346269, 2178309, 3524578]

i #=> 30
a30 + a31 #=> 2178309 + 3524578 #=> 5702887 < 4000000 #=> false, so stop.
```

This shows why `c` does not get updated when `i` equals `30`..